# Three different examples of three consecutive triangular numbers whose sum is a perfect square for n > or equal to 20

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Three different examples of three consecutive triangular numbers whose sum is a perfect square for n > or equal to 20. (In other words their sum must be greater than or equal to 400 and must be a perfect square).

I can use a program such as maple to write a script for it but I don't know where to even begin.

Using Joffan's suggestion I wrote out

$\frac{1}{2} j(j+1) + \frac{1}{2} k(k+1) + \frac{1}{2} l(l+1) = m^2 $

I am just not certain how I can translate this into maple's input language.

Comment: I suggest you write down the formula for three consecutive triangular numbers, and see if that suggests anything. At least it would indicate some thinking on your part, which always encourages response here. The formula for Triangular number $n$ is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: Well I know how i would set that up on paper.  It would be the sum from k to k+2 of [K(K+1)]/2 = some other arbitrary variable squared but I have no idea how to translate that into maple as I have never used it much and my teacher just glanced over it and expected us to learn how to use this complex program on our own.  I plan on asking about it tomorrow but I wanted to try to gain some insight prior to that.

Comment: Also  I am currently looking up tutorials on maple but it is a complex program and I don't understand how my teacher just expects us to understand how to input stuff into this program without knowing anything about the required formatting.

Comment: Try editing your post to add the three-part calculation - write it all out in terms of k (either the smallest number or the middle number, whichever you prefer (and define)).

Comment: tried to do it a bit and I know that the first three are 15 21 and 28 cause they equal 64 but that is too small to be a relevant answer.

Comment: You could say the first three are 0,1,3 if you allow $T_0$ into the picture. ----- What I suggest is that you edit the formula again to put k into all three sections instead of using separate letters (of course you will need to change the formula slightly to reflect that you are talking about the triangular numbers for (k-1),k,(k+1) in turn). Then take the factor of 1/2 outside brackets, then multiply out and gather terms.

Comment: My teacher in class set it up in maple using j k l and m and he had some really abstract looking code that I just wanted to get the general form of but I will try it your way and get back to you in a few minutes. I really appreciate the help this is after day 2 of an intro class I don't understand how the teacher expects us to know this already. I've literally never even heard of maple prior to last wednesday.

Comment: I'm thinking I should use the binomial thing where it is k+1 over a 2 in the brackets and just have (K+1 over 2) + (K+2 over 2) + (K+3 over 2) = to an arbitrary variable squared. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Well, if you're programming it then it's a bit different to trying to analyse it mathematically, which is the line I was going along. For a program, clarity is probably more important than efficiency at this point. Then I would just have a set of variables, moving forward in step like your teacher showed, and have a test square value which you also test and advance as required.

Comment: Yeah I just don't know how to actually put the query into maple as I have never used it before.  I guess I'm just going to have to get him to explain it to me before class or something.  Thanks again for all your help though.

Answer (score 2):

OK you have two different questions... programming in Maple is probably taken elsewhere, but I will say that for most programs, clarity is more important than efficiency. So having separate variables for your triangular numbers and for the square you're aiming at is fine if that makes your program clearer.

For mathematical analysis, though, if two items are related it's best to make that as explicit as possible. So your:

$\frac{1}{2} j(j+1) + \frac{1}{2} k(k+1) + \frac{1}{2} l(l+1) = m^2 $

since we're talking about $T_{k-1}+T_{k}+T_{k+1}, \to j=k-1$ and $l=k+1$ we can write as

$\frac{1}{2} (k-1)(k) + \frac{1}{2} k(k+1) + \frac{1}{2} (k+1)(k+2) = m^2 $

which could be simplified - or, more directly: 
$$\begin{align} 
T_{k-1}+T_{k}+T_{k+1} &= (T_{k} - k)+T_{k}+(T_{k}+(k+1))\\
&= 3T_k+1\\
&= 3\frac{1}{2}(k^2+k) + 1
\end{align}$$

which might help - it certainly shows that $m$ cannot be a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 0):

I will expand the solution of @Joffan.

The numbers $k > 0$ such that $k^2$ is a sum of three consecutive triangle numbers (namely $T_{k-1}$, $T_k$, $T_{k+1}$) can be found in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A129445) database. Their generating function is 
$$\frac{x(1-x)(1+3x+x^2)}{1-10x^2+x^4}.$$

And what may be surprising they satisfy relatively simple recurrence relation: $a_n = 10a_{n-2}-a_{n-4}$, where $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$, $a_3=8$ and $a_4 = 19$.

Comment: I always think OEIS is a little bit like a magic wand ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

For the equation:

$$\frac{a(a+1)}{2}+\frac{b(b+1)}{2}+\frac{c(c+1)}{2}=x^2$$

You can write the solution as:

$$a=-p^2+p-\frac{s(s+1)}{2}$$

$$b=-p^2-p-\frac{s(s+1)}{2}$$

$$c=s$$

$$x=p^2+\frac{s(s+1)}{2}$$

Or different.

$$a=-\frac{p(p+3)}{2}-s^2-s-1$$

$$b=-\frac{p(p+3)}{2}-s^2+s-1$$

$$c=-p-2$$

$$x=\frac{p(p+3)}{2}+s^2+1$$

$p,s$ - Integers asked us.  Not a lot not in a convenient form the recorded decision, but it is. Go to positive numbers is not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

What about this equation:

$$\frac{(k-1)k}{2}+\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}=x^2$$

For this we need to use the solutions of the Pell equation.

$$p^2-6s^2=1$$

To find solutions easily. Knowing the first solution $(p_1;s_2)$ - $(5;2)$

Knowing one solution, the following can be found by the formula.

$$p_2=5p_1+12s_1$$

$$s_2=2p_1+5s_1$$

Knowing any solution and using it, you can find the solution to this equation by the formula.

$$k=p(4s-p)$$

$$x=p^2-3ps+6s^2$$

Or different formula.

$$k=-2p^2-8ps-6s^2$$

$$x=2p^2+9ps+12s^2$$