# Special types of Triangular numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Find three consecutive triangular numbers whose sum is a perfect square.

I tried to simply use the formula that the nth triangular number is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and I added three conscutive triangular numbers. I tried to find cases in which the sum was a square number, but was unable to do so.

Comment: I tried to simply use the formula that the nth triangular number is n(n+1)/2 and I added three conscutive triangular numbers. I tried to find cases in which the sum was a square number, but was unable to do so.

Comment: The comment should be part of the question.

Comment: So $n(n+1)/2+(n+1)(n+2)/2+(n+2)(n+3)/2$ needs to be a square, right?

Comment: This simplifies to $(n+1)^2+(n+2)(n+3)/2$ and also to $n(n+1)/2+(n+2)^2$

Comment: There is more than one possible answer - do you only need to find 1?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}(3n^2+9n+8)$ needs to be square. Set $n = 0$ to get 4.

Comment: An example is $n=5$. Then, the numbers are $15,21,28$ and they add up to $64=8^2$

Comment: @5xum how do I make it part of the question?

Comment: @RMWGNE96 what to do after n(n+1)/2 + (n+2)^2

Comment: @RohanKalluraya There is an almost duplicate question, with an interesting answer re: the formula & OEIS sequence for the set of $k^2$ which are the sum of $3$ triangular numbers, at [Three different examples of three consecutive triangular numbers whose sum is a perfect square for n > or equal to 20](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123805/three-different-examples-of-three-consecutive-triangular-numbers-whose-sum-is-a?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Set it up as follows

$$
\frac{(n-1)n}{2} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
$$

which simplifies to

$$
\frac{3n^2+3n+2}{2},
$$

so you need to look at this fraction and decide for which $n$ is it a square.

You could also use the following two facts

- every pair of consecutive triangular numbers sums to a square
- the sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is equal to $n^2$

for another approach.

Hope this helped